# Autodesk Forge upload a file data management tutorial GET hubs endpoint command

Tags: get, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to set up a simple Autodesk Forge app. I want to upload a file to it and read that file, analyze it's data etc.

I've gone through the initial [Oauth](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/) token setup:

And then I ran the sample file and I got the following response:
(I replaced all sensitive information with ****)

```
**** Got Credentials { access_token: '***************',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3599,
  expires_at: 2018-10-20T16:57:45.977Z }
**** Creating bucket if not exist : bimbase_1.'***************',
**** Getting bucket details : bimbase_1.'***************',
**** Create bucket if not exist response: { bucketKey: 'bimbase_1.'***************',',
  bucketOwner: ''***************',',
  createdDate: 1540049926901,
  permissions:
   [ { authId: ''***************',', access: 'full' } ],
  policyKey: 'temporary' }
**** Getting all buckets
**** Uploading file. bucket:bimbase_1.'***************',
filePath:***************\samples\my-file.extension
**** Get all buckets response:
bimbase_1.***************
**** Upload file response: { bucketKey: 'bimbase_1.***************',
  objectId: 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:bimbase_1.***************/my-file.extension',
  objectKey: 'my-file.extension',
  sha1: '***************',
  size: 0,
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  location: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bimbase_1.***************/objects/my-file.extension' }
**** Deleting file from bucket:bimbase_1.***************, filename:my-file.extension
**** Delete file response status code: 200
```

Following this I went to the page on how to [upload a file](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/)
And I tried running the example command there:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer nFRJxzCD8OOUr7hzBwbr06D76zAT" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"
```

After a while I realized that this won't work because it's an example file... so I'm wondering where exactly do I find my "Bearer" key to put there instead of `nFRJxzCD8OOUr7hzBwbr06D76zAT`

Comment: **** Got Credentials { access_token: '***************',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3599,
  expires_at: 2018-10-20T16:57:45.977Z }

The access_token is the one given here, access_token: '****'

Comment: Excepted that for accessing hubs you need a 3legged token, not a 2legged token. you need to start with https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/

Comment: Hi Cyrille, thanks.
Where did you see that I need 3-legged token? From the tutorial I'm assuming I can do it with 2...

Comment: I got an error message:
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"status":"403","code":"BIM360DM_ERROR","title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM US.","detail":"You don't have permission to access this API"},{"status":"403","code":"BIM360DM_ERROR","title":"Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.","detail":"You don't have permission to access this API"}]}